# Grammatical Evolution (GE)

Tags: genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, genetic-programming

In the Grammatical Evolution (GE) algorithm (here the web: [grammatical-evolution.org](http://www.grammatical-evolution.org/)) there is the option to make the length of the individuals self-adaptive. I would like to know:

1. What is the most common strategy used when the individual's length is self-adaptive. In other words, how does the the length of the individual evolve.
2. Does it increase and decrease the size or just increase.
3. Is there any well documented or illustrative example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GE, the individuals are necessary variable-length in order to be able to encode programs (structures) of variable length.

**Initialization**

The initial population already consists of individuals of varying size. The initialization procedures may vary, but the one I'm familiar the most uses the grammar to create the individuals. You basically do the same thing as when you want to decode the individual into the program (using the grammar) but instead of choosing the grammar expansions using the individual, you do it the other way around - you choose the expansions randomly and record these random decisions. When the expansion is finished, your recorded decisions form an individual.

**Crossover**

The crossover operator in GE already modifies length of the indiviuals. It's a classical single-point crossover, but the crossover points are chosen completely randomly in both parents (in contrast to the classical single-point crossover from GAs where the parents are of the same length and the crossover point is aligned). This mechanism is capable of both growing and shrinking of the individuals.

Example on crossover: suppose you have two individuals and you have randomly chosen the crossover points

```
parent 1:  XXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXX
parent 2:  YYY|YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

After crossover, the children look like this

```
parent 1:  XXXXXXXXXXXX|YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
parent 2:  YYY|XXXX
```

As you can see, the length of the individuals was changed dramatically.

**Pruning**

However, there is a second mechanism that is used for length reduction only. It is the pruning operator. This operator, when invoked (with a probability, in the same way e.g. the mutation is invoked), deletes the non-active part  (i.e. if the grammar expansion finished before all codons were used, the remaining part is the non-active part) of the genotype.

Comment: Thank you @zegkljan, it is very useful your answer. Just two final questionns:                                                                                                   1 - When the individuals are created, are they created with the same length or there is some kind of variable to create them with different lenght.                                                                                                          2 - Once they are created there is any mechanism to increase the size of the indiidual? For example, a random probability to increase the individual with some codoms?

Comment: @JackGreen I dedited the answer. Hopefully it now shows how the individuals can get longer via crossover and how the initialization works.

Comment: Thank you @zegkljan, wonderful update. But, I don't fully understand the Initialization you commented. You try to decode an individual and if wrapping is going to happen, instead of that you add some codons at the end of the individual (avoidin always the wrapping). Is that right? Do you use a maximum length or something else, because the individual may become very very long.

Comment: @JackGreen No, you don't decode anything, instead you draw the numbers randomly and then save them. That makes an individual that, if decoded, produces the same program. Yes, the individual may become very very long this way but you can mitigate this by using a grammar that is "balanced" (see a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/CEC.2010.5586336) by Robin Harper). In short, a balanced grammar is such that the probability of any non-terminal symbol expanding to itself is equal to or lower than that of expanding to a terminal. If it is not, then you are likely to run away.

Comment: @zegkljan Do all individuals in a population have different lengths? For example, if my initial population has 20 individuals, will they all have the same length? Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel They can be (by chance) but they definitely don't have to be. It depends on how you initialize the population. You can, for example, initialize the derivation trees and reconstruct the genotypes back from them and then pad them to all have the same length. But you don't have to. It's genetic programming, everything is allowed if it works well for your problem :).